# Direct product and quotient groups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-sum, quotient-group

I am trying to convince myself that the following statement is true:

> Let $G, F$ be two group and $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Then
> $$G\cong H\oplus F\quad\text{if and only if}\quad G/H\cong F$$
> Where $\oplus$ symbolizes the direct product $H\oplus F=\{(h,f):h\in H,f\in F\}$.

The case $(\Rightarrow)$ is trivial since we only have to apply the First Isomorphism Theorem to the natural projection map $H\oplus F\to F$.

Unfortunately I am not able to show that the converse also holds.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because it's false?

Answer (score 3):

The converse is false.  Let $G=\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $H = \{0,2\}$.   Then $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ but of course $G$ cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Also, I was convinced this was a dupe, but after searching 3 pages worth of hits I didn't see it.  If it is a dupe, let me know and I will delete this.

Comment: I had the same feeling, with the same luck finding a duplicate.